# Migrating GeometryUtils.merge() to geometry.merge()

Tags: javascript, three.js

Migrating from r66 to r67 I get the message:

> DEPRECATED: GeometryUtils's .merge() has been moved to Geometry. Use geometry.merge( geometry2, matrix, materialIndexOffset ) instead.

It doesn't seem to be a direct conversion as the old code looks like this:

> THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(cgeo, cloudgeometry);

I have tried the following:

> cgeo.merge(cloudgeometry.geometry,cgeo.matrixWorld);

Edit, have also tried the following which produces the same result as above:

> cgeo.merge(cloudgeometry.geometry);

The results are a mesh which is compressed in area as if it is completely ignoring the positioning of the sub meshes which are being added to the new mesh I created, so rather than a large nice looking cloud I get a small white blog.

There is no documentation for this latest change so I am trying to understand how it works blind, if it was a simple 1 for 1 migration it would have been nice as it would have worked but it appears the way it works completely changed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure the matrix has been updated before merging. The code should probably look something like this:

```
cloudgeometry.updateMatrix();
cgeo.merge( cloudgeometry.geometry, cloudgeometry.matrix );
```

Comment: I'll try that here shortly and get back to you, but as I suspected there was more to the change than the old one liner, it's not a 1 for 1 change in otherwords, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Brilliant, that did it and apparently! Apparently I had that second argument completely wrong as I had cgeo rather than cloudgeometry and also matrixWorld rather than just matrix but it had been a 14 hour day that day so no wonder.. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, it's no longer a magic oneliner, but I think the current approach is much more powerful and clean.

Comment: Especially considering I believe I read it was improved performance. Am calling this one solved, thanks!